# Android, Expandable list view items focus issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I have an expandable listview. I have put some data and everything seems ok but I have three textview in group layout when i click on group textviews child view not shown and when click other area of listview child view successful shows.

i think i have a problem in **textview Focus** but i try a lot remove focus from the textview but i failed.

[This is the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98ynL.png)
In my screenshot define, when i click inside blue outline area listview click event not working but when i click on red outline area perfectly clicked and child view shows.
how can i resolve click issue.

Thanks in advance.

This is my code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/container"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:divider="@color/divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

View_Group.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llOrderFooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/baseWhite"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivvegIndicator"
                    android:layout_width="6dp"
                    android:layout_height="6dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/green_circle"
                   />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivNonVegIndicator"
                    android:layout_width="6dp"
                    android:layout_height="6dp"

                    android:background="@drawable/red_circle" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <com.entree.entree.views.RobottowCondenced
                android:id="@+id/foodName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="FOODNAME"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

            <com.entree.entree.views.RobottowCondenced
                android:id="@+id/foodPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="PRICE"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:textColor="#000" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"

            android:paddingRight="2dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"


                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="6dp"
                    android:layout_height="6dp"

                    android:background="@drawable/green_circle" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                    android:layout_width="6dp"
                    android:layout_height="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"

                    android:background="@drawable/red_circle" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.entree.entree.views.RobottowCondencedLight
                android:id="@+id/foodDesc"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/baseDark"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="grtgrtgrtgrtgrtgrtgdscdscsdcdscdscsrtgrtgrtgrtg5htyjnsrtg5hqegrtertgertg"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"

                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
                android:lines="3"

                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.06" />

            <com.entree.entree.views.RobottowCondencedLight
                android:id="@+id/qty"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|right"
                android:gravity="end|right"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:enabled="false"

                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textColor="@color/baseDark"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:visibility="visible"

                android:layout_weight="0.17"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

View_Child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llAddFood"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/LightGreen"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="3"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/baseWhite"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="Customize"
                android:textColor="@color/baseWhite"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="14dp"

                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/baseWhite"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRemoveFood"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="@color/baseWhite"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="20dp"

                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/baseWhite"></View>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAddFood"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="+"
                android:textColor="@color/baseWhite"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/baseWhite"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

FoodListAdapter.class

```
 public class FoodExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Food> arrFood = new ArrayList<Food>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private FoodChangeListener fcListener;
    private Restaurant resObj;


    public FoodExpandableListAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Food> arrFood, Restaurant resObj) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.arrFood = arrFood;
        this.resObj = resObj;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    public FoodExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewfooter, null);
        }

        Button AddButton=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddFood);
        Button RemoveButton=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemoveFood);

        AddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,groupPosition+"Add",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        RemoveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,groupPosition+"Remove",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
       /* TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);*/
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.arrFood.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.arrFood.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }



    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Food food = arrFood.get(groupPosition);
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
          /*  LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);*/

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewheader, null);


            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.foodName = (RobottowCondenced) convertView.findViewById(R.id.foodName);
        holder.foodPrice = (RobottowCondenced) convertView.findViewById(R.id.foodPrice);
        holder.foodDesc = (RobottowCondencedLight) convertView.findViewById(R.id.foodDesc);
        holder.foodquantity = (RobottowCondencedLight) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        holder.llOrderFooter = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llOrderFooter);
        holder.vegOnly = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivvegIndicator);
        holder.VetnNonVeg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivNonVegIndicator);


        holder.foodName .setFocusable(false);
        holder.foodDesc .setFocusable(false);
        holder.foodDesc.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        holder.foodName.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

        holder.foodName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Cilck", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        holder.foodPrice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Cilck", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        if ((groupPosition % 2) == 0) {
            holder.llOrderFooter.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4dc4c4c4"));
        } else {
            holder.llOrderFooter.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7f7f9"));
        }



        if (food.getVegOnly().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            holder.vegOnly.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.VetnNonVeg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.VetnNonVeg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.vegOnly.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.foodName.setText(food.getFoodName());
        holder.foodDesc.setText(food.getFoodDesc());
        holder.foodPrice.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.Rs) + " " + String.valueOf(food.getPrice()));




        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }


    public void setOnDataChangeListener(FoodChangeListener onDataChangeListener) {
        fcListener = onDataChangeListener;
        int price = calculateTotalCost();
        if (fcListener != null)
            fcListener.onDataChanged(price);
    }
    private int calculateTotalCost() {
        int price = 0;
        for (OrderItem item : EntreeApplication.arrUserOtderItems) {
            price = price + item.getItemTotal();
        }
        return price;
    }
    public class ViewHolder {
        RobottowCondenced foodName;
        RobottowCondencedLight foodDesc;
        RobottowCondenced foodPrice;
        ImageView foodImage;
        FrameLayout ffFoodContent;
        LinearLayout llAddFood, llOrderFooter;
        Button btnRemoveFood;
        Button btnAddFood;
        Button btnCancel;
        LinearLayout llFoodFooter;
        ImageView vegOnly, VetnNonVeg;
        RobottowCondencedLight foodquantity;
    }
    }
```

Comment: i think this not problem of focus of textview .

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper so please tell me what is a problem?

Comment: you have any button or edittext or checkbox in parent?

Comment: Remove focusableInTouchMode and Focusable from parent view then check

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper no i have only imageview textview in group xml and 3 buttons in child xml.

Comment: in adapter cut paste all componants which u bind  inside if Convertview==Null condition.

Comment: and other thing you have written code for textview on click listener.so may be its make problem.

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper TextView Click event i written for testing only i remove it. and paste all components inside  if Convertview==Null.. but not working...

Comment: have you remove focus properties from parent Layout of parent view